# Is it safe to use the USB 3.0 on this motherboard if it has broken pin?

Tags: usb, motherboard

I have a broken USB 3.0 header pin on an ASUS Prime B250M-A. After checking the USB 3.0 on front panel it still works, but is it safe? Will be any damage possible?

[image: USB 3.0 header image]

This is from the ASUS Prime B250M-A manual:

[image: B250M-A manual image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing pin is on the keyway side on the right hand away from the keyway. Downwards from your manual image.

By the looks of it that is a Ground pin. I would assume it is the ground shield for one of the two pairs nearby either P1_D+/- or P2_D+/-.

Most shields in the cables are connected together by virtue of proximity so you may well be fine.

Worst case is that one of the pairs has a slightly iffy ground signal. Best case is that the connector gets earthed via one of the other grounds.

It shouldn't be dangerous, I'd be surprised if it cause any damage. At worst it is not quite as good as it should be.

---

It looks like the ground is for one of the USB2 pairs. I would hope that the grounds for the connectors are linked in the shells at the connectors or the other grounds for that connector are linked in the end device making this one pin "just" an extra ground. In all honesty I'd be surprised to see anything more than an occasional USB2 packet retransmission.

If both connectors "just work" then the other grounds are functional and this one can be thought of as an extra cable drain wire that isn't connected.

Comment: “At worst it is not quite as good as it should be.” Meaning that if this is a USB 3.0 header, then the speed might not be as fast as expected? Possibly even downgrading to USB 2.0.

Comment: It looks like the ground is for one of the USB2 pairs. I would hope that the grounds for the connectors are linked in the shells at the connectors or the other grounds for that connector are linked in the end device making this one pin "just" an extra ground. I'd be surprised to see anything more than an occasional USB2 packet retransmission. If it "just works" then the other grounds are functional and this one can be thought of as an extra cable drain wire that isn't connected.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explain :)

Comment: @zaeraan I think you're fine. I did just add a bit. If it were one of the other signal wires, literally the other pin above that one, then it might have broken something, but we usually have extra grounds just to cover bases.